# JavaScript, Download image by base64 url

Tags: javascript, image, download, base64

So I have a url, which is a base-64 encoded. I need to create blob url to download this file. I could not decoded that url, because I need to hide real url. It should be encoded. Next code does not work, if I open blob url, there will be empty screen.

```
const res = await fetch('data:image/jpeg;base64,aHR0cHM6Ly9taXJvLm1lZGl1bS5jb20vbWF4Lzg3NS8xKnZadV9hdFd2aHdEcnBLNGEybWhha2cuanBlZw==');
const blob = await res.blob();
const myUrl= URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: That base64 string is invalid and incredibly short.

Comment: @John it's not invalid, it's an encoded url. Paste it into this site: https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: I got this url here. You could check it if you encode it. 
https://miro.medium.com/max/875/1*vZu_atWvhwDrpK4a2mhakg.jpeg

Comment: You encoded a text string into base64 and you're trying to treat a string as a jpeg file format. Its not valid. You need to encode a image file, not the url of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide your urls, you should create a proxy server, which works just like a url shortener. Base64 is more of a nuisance.

However, if you want to download a base64 url, you must decode it first before you fetch it.

```
fetch(atob("aHR0cHM6Ly9taXJvLm1lZGl1bS5jb20vbWF4Lzg3NS8xKnZadV9hdFd2aHdEcnBLNGEybWhha2cuanBlZw=="))
    .then(res => res.blob())
    .then(blob => {
        //whatever
    });
```

Read more about **atob**() and **btoa**():

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob